# npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME npm ERR! Invalid tag name "@": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes

Tags: npm, npm-install

When I type `npm install @ craco / craco --save` I get the error message `npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME npm ERR! Invalid tag name "@": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.`

I am using a ubuntu server and I'm trying to set up a Solana token exchange. All my apps and ubuntu run the newest version.

https://telegra.ph/Crypton---Launching-a-decentralized-exchanger---commands-from-the-video-07-12

This is the tutorial that I'm using.

This command worked `npm install -g serve`

I've tried `npm install @ craco / craco --save` in the directory oyster-swap too, but it also didn't work.

When I type `npm install`I get the following warning: `npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/package.json' npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/package.json' npm WARN root No description npm WARN root No repository field. npm WARN root No README data npm WARN root No license field.`

Comment: `npm install @craco/craco --save` (remove spaces)

Comment: I did in the oyster-swap directory. I got the following warning ```npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported (couldn't include whole warning, was too long)

+ @craco/craco@5.9.0
added 1859 packages from 1044 contributors and audited 1873 packages in 60.211s

78 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 160 vulnerabilities (113 moderate, 43 high, 4 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details```

Comment: It is installed, that logs are just warnings and info, not errors. Just an advice: first learn stuff, don't just blindly follow tutorials.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

npm install "@craco/craco"